# Use Azure Database (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I'm new in ASP.NET Development

I create MVC Project and as I understood it creates with default .mdf database.

I working with it and all was great, but I think about deploying app to azure.

So I need to use azure database.

I create it , all ok.

I read article how connect to azure db.

As I understood , I need connection string

Here it is

```
Server=tcp:smartsolutionsserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=smartdatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

As I understood I need to paste it to Web.Release.config

I do this, so now it have look like this

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection"
    connectionString="Server=tcp:smartsolutionsserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=smartdatabase;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=*********;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But as I understood .mdf database connections wrote in Web.config file

And looks like this

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SmartSolutions-20170124034333.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SmartSolutions-20170124034333;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Tell me, how I can connect to azure database and use it instead of local .mdf database?

Thank's so much for help.

**UPDATE**

I try to add 2 new tables and publish app. After connecting to database from SQL Server Object Explorer, I see that tables added.

But when I try to register new user I see this

On local all ok

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xc9I.png)

Comment: Put the specific error message as text in your post. Imgur is down.

Comment: Did you whitelist the IP address of the web app on the Azure SQL Server?

Comment: You need to log the error occurring or turn custom errors off in Web.config to see it. Otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

So my error was in `The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created`

I go to table `__MigrationHistory` and delete row. After that, all okay. All works

@ juunas Thank's for advice. I do this and see error. Also it can visible if you use IIS Console